# UIWindow + lockscreen issue

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

straight to the point: Our app has `UITableView` with `UITableViewCell` that has `AVPlayerViewController` inside (its view) + custom video controls. One of the controls is **fullscreen** mode. Note that everything works perfectly - loading video, reusing, even the fullscreen.

**Fullscreen** functionality is based on creating new `UIWindow`, setting its `rootViewController` to the videoplayer and making it keyAndVisible - basically showing fullscreen `AVPlayerViewController` from cell subview on tap

The issue comes when user **locks** his device - after unlocking, the fullscreen window "disappears" and app is frozen / stuck on previous screen (the list with video cell, text cells.. - the one that made the new  `UIWindow`)

The `UIWindow` (video window) is there, but without content (no subviews, VCs..) on top of the main (app, tableview list..) `UIWindow` - refer to **pictures**.

This issue is **not** happening on Simulator - only real devices.

View hierarchy debug before locking the device and showing the video on fullscreen (with new `UIWindow`):

[image: View debug before freeze]

View hierarchy debug after unlocking the device and app freezing on previous `UIWindow`:

[image: View debug after freeze]

Is there any possible fix? Or a better way of presenting `AVPlayerViewController` from `UITableViewCell` (while playing and without stopping the video)?

*Note: the bug happens even if we remove landscape / portrait orientation changing, the issue seems to be related to UIWindow*

*PS: sorry for hiding the names in the pictures - NDA...*

Comment: It looks like the window is being deallocated - can you profile it with the `Instruments`?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I tried -> the UIWindow is not getting deallocated, not even the controller, player etc.

Comment: I tried to display a `AVPlayerViewController` in a `UIWindow` on my device, and lock the screen, but it stays on top when I unlock it - you could try making the window `keyAndVisible` again when the app resumes (in the application delegate)